# Using Logic in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to do something like this in TSQL (SQL Server 2005):

```
IF (Column1 = x)
{
     --CTE statement
}
ELSE
{
    --SQL statement
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that part of a query? or on its own?

Outside of `SELECT`, you have:

```
IF ([test])
BEGIN
     [true branch]
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    [false branch]
END
```

The branches can do anything, including use CTEs etc.

Inside a query, you have [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT ..., CASE WHEN Column1=x THEN [answer1]
                 ELSE [answer2] END, ...
```

However, you can't do a CTE inside `CASE`

Comment: I'm wrapping this in an SP. I do not know if this is doable at all.

Comment: Or maybe I should do the logic inside the CTE? How to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The CTE applies to the whole statement and is not standalone. It's a clause or sub-construct in a larger SQL construct.

This works if the output from each statement is different

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1 = x)
BEGIN
    ;WITH cStuff AS
    (
        ...
    )
    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM
        tables and cStuff
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM
        tables
END
```

This works if the output is the same:

```
;WITH cStuff AS
(
    ...
)
SELECT 
    ...
FROM
    tables and cStuff
WHERE
    column1 = x
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    ...
FROM
    tables
WHERE
    column1 <> x
```

Otherwise, I'm unsure what you want to achieve...